# Prove the convergence of $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\alpha +x_n}$, with $x_0=\sqrt \alpha$ using fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the well known sequence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\alpha +x_n}, x_0=\sqrt \alpha, \alpha>0$.

How would one use the fixed point theorem to prove that it converges to $\sqrt{a} \ \ \ \forall a>0?$

Trying to see whether $f(x) = \sqrt{\alpha+x}$ is a contructor yields following:
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha+\xi}}| |x-y| \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}} |x-y|,$$
which suggests that $f(x)$ is a contractor only when $\sqrt{\alpha} > \frac{1}{2} $ or $\alpha>\frac{1}{4}$.  But this is obviously false. What's wrong here?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4055264/examining-recurrence-relation-for-its-limit-and/4055358#4055358)  and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333050/how-do-i-prove-the-sequence-x-n1-sqrt-alpha-x-n-with-x-0-sqrt-alpha?rq=1) answers might contain some hints to your question.

Comment: I think when you say "contructor" you mean ["contraction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping)

Comment: @CalvinKhor but of course, pardon the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x) =\sqrt{\alpha + x}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha + x}}$.  If $x \geq 1$, then $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha + x}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha + 1}} \leq \frac 1 2.$$

This shows that $f(x) = \sqrt{\alpha + x}$ is a contraction on $[1,\infty)$, so there is a fixed point in $[1,\infty)$.

If $x < 1$, since the sequence defined by iterating $f$ is nondecreasing, either it converges to a point below 1 or eventually it ends up in $[1,\infty)$.  In either case it is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

For the fixed point theorem you need a function f that goes from a closed and bounded space in itself, i. e., $ f: [a, b] \longrightarrow [a, b] $. Usually what you do is calculate the derivative of $ f $ and see that $ f^{\prime} \in (a, b) $. Then using the fact that $ a \leq x \leq b $ you deduce that $ | f^{\prime} (x) | <1 $. So I think what is failing is the fact that you have not defined the interval for $ f $.

Answer (score 1):

When we write
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha+\xi}}\right||x-y|,\ $$
notice that not only is $\xi$ positive, it's greater than $1$ (for great enough $x$ and $y$, and for $\xi$ is just between $x$ and $y$). So we get
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha+\xi}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi}}<\frac{1}{2}.\ $$
That's to say, for each $\alpha>0$, the sequence is convergent.